# Laravel 5 Ajax url not executing route

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I followed this [tutorial on dynamic droplists](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-make-simple-dependent-dropdown-using-jquery-ajax-in-laravel-5example.html) but my 2nd droplist is still empty. The route is never reached. 
This statement in below js file executes correctly `console.log(sportID);` This line in controller is never reached: `print_r('I am here');die();`

view:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label for="sport" class="col-md-3 control-label">Current Sport</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control" name="sport" id="sport">

            <option disabled selected value> -- select an option --</option>

            @foreach($sports as $sport)
                <option value="{{ $sport->id }}">{{ $sport->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group ">
    <label for="position" class="col-md-3 control-label">Current Position</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select name="position" id="position" class="form-control">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

routes:

```
Route::get('/admin/athlete/new', [
        'uses' => 'NprController@getCreateAthlete',
        'as'   => 'admin.new_athlete'
]);
Route::get('/admin/athlete/new/ajax/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'NprController@myformAjax',
        'as'   => 'admin.new_athlete_ajax'
]);
```

controller method:

```
public function myformAjax($id)
{
    print_r('I am here');die();
    $positions = Position::where('sport_id','=',$id)->get();        
    return json_encode($positions);
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[name="sport"]').on('change', function () {

        var sportID = $(this).val();

        if (sportID) {
            console.log(sportID);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/admin/athlete/new/ajax/" + sportID,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('select[name="position"]').empty();
                    $('select[name="position"]').append(' Please choose one');
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        $('select[name="position"]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('select[name="position"]').empty();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What response are you getting in your console?

Comment: I would start debugging by hitting Route::get('/admin/athlete/new/ajax/{id}', function() {
  return "Laravel";
 });
If you are hitting it, check request() output.

Comment: it's not type: "GET" but method: "GET"

Comment: I get response 404 in console. Also added token to the Ajax, no difference. Changing type to method also makes no difference.

Comment: It's working if I change the url to this: `url: 'http://localhost/npr/public/admin/athlete/new/ajax'+sportID,` how can I make it relative?

Comment: `url : './new/ajax'+sportID` did the trick. Not sure why it needs the /new/ajax and not just the /ajax, because the screen I'm on has the /new in the url. But the fields are working now.

Comment: You should have to declare one global variable something like host and catch base URL in host variable then just append other address with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the url to `url: 'http://localhost/npr/public/admin/athlete/new/ajax'+sportID‌​` worked, and making it relative, the following worked: `url : './new/ajax'+sportID`

This was for Laravel 5.3